# Java - Error Non-default namespace can not map to empty URI in XML 1.0 documents

Tags: java, xml, soap

I try to invoke a webservice in Java. Mainly I followed this [link](https://alesaudate.wordpress.com/2010/08/09/how-to-dynamically-select-a-certificate-alias-when-invoking-web-services/) and also I solved several problems with google and other questions of stackoverflow. However, I get an error that I can not solve:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Non-default namespace can not map to empty URI (as per Namespace 1.0 # 2) in XML 1.0 documents
```

I think that the problem is in the xml that I created but I see well.

SOAPUI request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:acc="http://url/acceso">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <acc:petitionSession>
         <acc:codUser/>
         <acc:pass>?</acc:pass>
         <acc:codOp>?</acc:codOp>
      </acc:petitionSession>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Request I generated:

```
   <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:acc="http://url/acceso">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <acc:petitionSession>
                <acc:codUser/>
                <acc:pass>user1</acc:pass>
                <acc:codOp>Temp1</acc:codOp>
            </acc:petitionSession>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Code:

Dispatch dispatcher = getDispatcher(wsdlLocation, namespace, serviceName, portName);

```
dispatcher.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.SOAPACTION_USE_PROPERTY, Boolean.TRUE);
dispatcher.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.SOAPACTION_URI_PROPERTY, soapActionUri);
```

...
...

```
 public static SOAPMessage construirMensaje() throws SOAPException, IOException{
        
        MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
         SOAPMessage soapMsg = factory.createMessage();
         SOAPPart part = soapMsg.getSOAPPart();
         
         SOAPEnvelope envelope = part.getEnvelope();
         envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("acc", "http://url/acceso");
         SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
         SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();
         
         SOAPBodyElement element = body.addBodyElement(envelope.createName("petitionSession", 
                 "acc", null));
         element.addChildElement(body.addBodyElement(envelope.createName("codUser", 
                 "acc", null)));
         
         SOAPBodyElement pass = body.addBodyElement(envelope.createName("pass", 
                 "acc", null));
         pass.addTextNode("user1");
         element.addChildElement(pass);
         
         SOAPBodyElement codOp = body.addBodyElement(envelope.createName("codOp", 
                 "acc", null));
         codOp.addTextNode("Temp1");
         element.addChildElement(codOp);
         
         soapMsg.writeTo(System.out);

         FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream("SoapMessage.xml");
         soapMsg.writeTo(fOut);
     
         System.out.println();
         
         return soapMsg;
        
    }
```

Any idea?

Regards.

Comment: I find the problem that was in the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem that was in the header that it wasn`t built well. It needed to add:

```
MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI  + "name");
```

Comment: the origin code header has what problem?